# How can I dynamically fill a table-cell with background-color?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I've got a problem with a school schedule, wich is coded in php/html. The lessons are filled in a html table (surprise!!) and a filled cell has to get a background color. The problem is, that the table is dynamically filled with data, so it's not possible to give the td-tag the background-color. Here is my code:

```
echo"<td id='cell' style='width:15%'>";
foreach($plan->result as $res){
   if($res->date == "20131007" && $item->startTime == $res->startTime){
      foreach ($res->kl as $kl){
         echo getKlasseById($ch, $kl->id).", ";
      }
      echo"<script type=\"text/javascript\">
      var td = document.getElementById('cell');
      td.style.backgroundColor='#FF8000';</script>";
   }
}
```

What this does is filling the fist cell of the table with the background-color and then nothing (concerning the color).

**EDIT**

Ok, I solved my problem. As my programming prof would say, I tried to shoot pigeons with fusion bombs. I just put a `<div>` around the foreach-loop with the desired background-color. 
Anyway, thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you not just add CSS rules for a given `td` class, and set the class to something like `colouredCell`?

Answer (score 1):

Create a CSS class with the desired background color:

```
.colored { background-color: yourcolor; }
```

And, when you echo the `<td>`, add the class to it.

Instead of rendering the td BEFORE the if, you may do that inside the if, if that's the main problem!..

```
echo "<td id=\"cell\" class=\"colored\">";
```

To be more clear, I mean that instead of this:

```
echo"<td id='cell' style='width:15%'>";
foreach($plan->result as $res){
   if($res->date == "20131007" && $item->startTime == $res->startTime){
      foreach ($res->kl as $kl){
         echo getKlasseById($ch, $kl->id).", ";
      }
      echo"<script type=\"text/javascript\">
      var td = document.getElementById('cell');
      td.style.backgroundColor='#FF8000';</script>";
   }
}
```

You may do this:

```
foreach($plan->result as $res){
   if($res->date == "20131007" && $item->startTime == $res->startTime){
      echo"<td id='cell' style='width:15%' class='colored'>";
      foreach ($res->kl as $kl){
         echo getKlasseById($ch, $kl->id).", ";
      }
   }
   else {
     echo"<td id='cell' style='width:15%'>";
     // Whatever goes into the else, if needed.
   }
}
```

Anyway.. You're not closing the `<td>`, are you? :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Well, I'm closing the <td>, just forgot to post it here ;)
I tried your solution before I posted here, but the result was, that it doesn't fill the cells with the correct data anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Why like that? Why not use PHP instead. All these samll Javascript elements only slow down the page, and makes the page slower to parse by browsers. PHP+ some classes are way more efficient

```
foreach($plan->result as $res){
    $backgroundColor = "";
    if($res->date == "20131007" && $item->startTime == $res->startTime){
      foreach ($res->kl as $kl){
         echo getKlasseById($ch, $kl->id).", ";
     }
    $backgroundColor = "#FF8000";
   }
}
echo"<td id='cell' style='width:15%;background-color: ".$backgroundColor."'>";
```

Small sidenote: Your code is a bit unclear so I'm not sure wether I put the code in the proper order or with the proper statements, but you catch my drift

Comment: I proposed to make a css class because it usually is recommended to use classes instead of filling styles while making objects, isn't it? :)

Comment: If it has multiple occurences a class would be better, yes. I gave the inline style method as en example based on the current code :)

Comment: Of course a css-class would be far better than what I did there. It was just to give the code a try.
The foreach loop has to be placed in the td-tag unfortunately. So this solution looks quite good, but won't work for me. But thanx a lot for your help.